# How to print full content of win form c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, developer-tools

I have win form and I want to print the entire contents.
For now, use code that prints only the part that is displayed, not print the entire contents of below.
I checked google but did not find anything specific on the topic.
Can you do the optimization of this code to print the entire contents of the page?
The strange thing is that the content comes half a page to say there are half a page to be filled with the rest of the content
[Here is screenshot:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQyd1.png)
[image]

```
private System.IO.Stream streamToPrint;

string streamType;

[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImportAttribute("gdi32.dll")]
private static extern bool BitBlt
(
    IntPtr hdcDest, // handle to destination DC
    int nXDest, // x-coord of destination upper-left corner
    int nYDest, // y-coord of destination upper-left corner
    int nWidth, // width of destination rectangle
    int nHeight, // height of destination rectangle
    IntPtr hdcSrc, // handle to source DC
    int nXSrc, // x-coordinate of source upper-left corner
    int nYSrc, // y-coordinate of source upper-left corner
    System.Int32 dwRop // raster operation code
);

private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(this.streamToPrint);

    int x = e.MarginBounds.X;
    int y = e.MarginBounds.Y;

    int width = image.Width;
    int height = image.Height;
    if ((width / e.MarginBounds.Width) > (height / e.MarginBounds.Height))
    {
        width = e.MarginBounds.Width;
        height = image.Height * e.MarginBounds.Width / image.Width;
    }
    else
    {
        height = e.MarginBounds.Height;
        width = image.Width * e.MarginBounds.Height / image.Height;
    }
    System.Drawing.Rectangle destRect = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(image, destRect, 0, 0, image.Width, image.Height, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
    }

    private void printButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 

        String filename = System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName();

        Graphics g1 = this.CreateGraphics();
        Image MyImage = new Bitmap(this.ClientRectangle.Width, this.ClientRectangle.Height, g1);
        Graphics g2 = Graphics.FromImage(MyImage);
        IntPtr dc1 = g1.GetHdc();
        IntPtr dc2 = g2.GetHdc();
        BitBlt(dc2, 0, 0, this.ClientRectangle.Width, this.ClientRectangle.Height, dc1, 0, 0, 13369376);
        g1.ReleaseHdc(dc1);
        g2.ReleaseHdc(dc2);
        MyImage.Save(filename, ImageFormat.Png);
        FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        StartPrint(fileStream, "Image");
        fileStream.Close();
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(filename))
        {
            System.IO.File.Delete(filename);
        }
    }


    private void printPreviewDialog1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public void StartPrint(Stream streamToPrint, string streamType)
    {

        this.printDocument1.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(printDocument1_PrintPage);

        this.streamToPrint = streamToPrint;

        this.streamType = streamType;

        System.Windows.Forms.PrintDialog PrintDialog1 = new PrintDialog();

        PrintDialog1.AllowSomePages = true;
        PrintDialog1.ShowHelp = true;
        PrintDialog1.Document = printDocument1;
        DialogResult result = PrintDialog1.ShowDialog();
        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            printDocument1.Print();
        }
    }       
 }
}
```

Comment: Does the `png` image has the correct size? If so I think it's a page-range or scaling setting that might disturb the printing.

Comment: The only thing I found somewhat my works is this code and do not know how to change the amount of coverage?